# What version of Nautilus fixed the SFTP always asking for password bug?

Tags: nautilus, sftp

I'm running Ubuntu, and I was wondering if anyone knows what release this bug was fixed in Nautilus?

The bug is Nautilus, no matter what setting you use for storing the password: "Remember Forever, Until I sign out" would ask for it every time.

I'm only asking for the version number of the package I need to obtain (whether it be nautilus or some library it uses).

This is the best I can find: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1299177

Comment: @user535733 - updated question with bug report

Comment: Hmmm. Looks like that bug was closed without any fix at all; not enough folks filed, nobody who suffered the problem cared enough to triage it,  etc. One comment says the problem persisted in 15.04. Nautilus 3.18.4 (in 16.04) and higher might not have the problem.

Comment: Bugs are off-topic in Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Direct discussion of a bug is indeed off-topic, agreed. Whether or not a problem is a bug, how to use the bug tracker, how to triage a bug, etc. are on-topic. I think the OP is asking for help understanding the terse reporting in the bug tracker, which seems on-topic...though a seeming dead-end in this case.